# Cannot find folder error when Running SQl job for SSIS package

Tags: ssis, ssms

Could not load package "\\Servername\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Test\Test\ExcelTest.dtsx" because of error 0xC0014049.  Description: Cannot find folder "\\Servername\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Test\Test\ExcelTest.dtsx".

I have ssis package in my local machine. I have logged into test server. When running sql job with the package path with UNC path, the above error is throwing.
Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: replace server path with your local path and  make sure that the account executing the package has rights to do so

Comment: Yes i did with my server path and gave rights. I also tried by moving the package file to main server. Its throwing error " Unable to load package as XML because of package does not have valid XML format".

Comment: is it working on  local machine ?

Comment: Yes, Looks like there is a version issue. By importing and deploying into the ssisdb, got the clear errors why it is not supporting.